# Using Spinner And List Views with setOnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, spinner

I'm supposed to make a task , I have a spinner connected with a String array x , this array contains three values , so I want when clicking any choice of the spinner a specific list view will will give a specific three values and , this is my code :

```
public class Four extends ActionBarActivity {
String x [] = {"Jordan","Saudi Arabia", "Syria"};
String Jordan[] = {"Amman","Aqaba","Sarqa"};
String Saudi[] = {"Riyadh","Jeddah","Khobar"};
String Syria[] = {"Hems","Halab","Demashk"};

Spinner sp1 ;
ListView lv1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.four);

    lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    // Jordan List View
    ArrayAdapter<String> jor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Jordan);
    lv1.setAdapter(jor);

    // Saudi Arabia List View
    ArrayAdapter<String> saud = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Saudi);
    lv1.setAdapter(saud);

    // Syria List View
    ArrayAdapter<String> syr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Syria);
    lv1.setAdapter(syr);




    sp1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> a = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item , x);
    sp1.setAdapter(a);

    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }


        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });




}
```

}

Comment: is my question hard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thir parameter of `onItemSelected()` (`int arg2` in your example, but I would suggest you rename them) is the position you selected in the `Spinner`. So you could implement that method like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    if (position == 0)
        lv1.setAdapter(jor);
    else if (position == 1)
        lv1.setAdapter(saud);
    else if (position == 1);
        lv1.setAdapter(syr);
}
```

Remember that all the variables involved (lv1, jor, saud, syr) must be defined as final to be used inside the anonymous class, e.g.

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> jor = ...
final ArrayAdapter<String> saud = ...
```